# cURL+redirect with cookie

Tags: php, cookies, curl

How i can redirect user to another web site with cookie?
Im using this code

```
<?php
$fields_string = 'client_login=jadro&client_pass=jadro&client_remember=on&action=client_login';
$options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,  
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,   
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.1.7) Gecko/20091221 Firefox/3.5.7 FirePHP/0.3",
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => false,     
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,   
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
    );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://orion10.ru');
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count(explode('&',$fields)));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cooc.txt'); 
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cooc.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd()."/cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd()."/cookies.txt"); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
//header("Location: http://orion10.ru".session_name().'='.session_id());
header('Refresh: 15; URL='.$url['http://orion10.ru']);
exit();
?>
```

I need authorize user to another site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL is being executed on ***your*** server. Therefore, the website in question thinks that your server is the user. i.e. When you redirect the ***actual*** user to the website in question, it won't recognize them. [Read this.](http://thisinterestsme.com/php-redirecting-a-form-with-post-variables/)